# How can I copy all files with a given extension?

Tags: perl

I need to copy all `*.exe` files in some directory to other virtual drive .

If I was writing batch script I would do `xcopy "%mycopyposition%\*.exe"`.

But I think it will be a bad idea in Perl script .

I seen a [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Copy) module, but couldn't see how to do that.

Comment: please read perldoc File::Copy

Comment: of course, you will also need to loop over the exe's

Comment: I already read it but no information about my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
use File::Copy;
for my $file (<*.exe>) {
    # Copies from directory $mycopyposition to current directory.
    copy  "$mycopyposition/$file", $file or die "copy $file failed: $!";
}
```

Comment: Note his `xcopy` copies *from* `%mycopyposition%` not to. And, while we are using modules, recommend using `File::Spec->catfile` to concatenate paths.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm not familar with `xcopy`.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is an excellent idea to use `xcopy`. It does what you want. Plus, it preserves time stamps and other attributes. Has some very useful options.